# Pass image data from view to controller on update button click in update page

Tags: image, asp.net-core, model-view-controller, asp.net-core-mvc, image-upload

Here on the update page load the image is displayed on the web page .

On update button click how to pass the image data(IFormFile) form view to controller.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to pass IFormFile from view to controller,you can use a input which type is file,view cannot pass a `<img/>` to controller.Here is a demo:

View:

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="image"/>
    <input type="submit" value="submit"/>
</form>
```

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
        public IActionResult Main(IFormFile image)
        {
            return View();
        }
```

result:
[image]

Or you can pass a path to controller,and controller get the file with a path.
Image:

[image]

View:

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input name="image" value="1.jpg" hidden/>

    <img src="~/images/1.jpg" />
    <input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
        public IActionResult Main(string image)
        {
            string path = "./wwwroot/images/" + image;
            IFormFile File;
            using (var stream = System.IO.File.OpenRead(path))
            {
                File = new FormFile(stream, 0, stream.Length, null, Path.GetFileName(stream.Name));
            }
            return View();
        }
```

result:
[image]